# show ajax messagebox for sending form data

Tags: php, html, ajax, messagebox, contact-form

Hello I have a contact form, which send form data to an email, but the problem is when data has been sent show success or error message in other php page but I wan to show the message in same page without refreshing page.
this is index.html:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="info">Give Your Feedback!</div>
    <form action="mail_handler.php" method="post" name="form" class="form-box">
        <label for="name">Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required><br>
        <label for="email">Email ID</label><br>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required><br>
        <label for="phone">Phone</label><br>
        <input type="tel" name="phone" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Phone" required><br>
        <label for="message">Message</label><br>
        <textarea name="msg" class="msg-box" placeholder="Enter Your Message Here..." required></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="sub-btn">
    </form>
</div>
```

and this is mail_handler.php:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $msg=$_POST['msg'];

    $to='mehrdad3373@gmail.com'; // Receiver Email ID, Replace with your email ID
    $subject='Form Submission';
    $message="Name :".$name."\n"."Phone :".$phone."\n"."Wrote the following :"."\n\n".$msg;
    $headers="From: ".$email;

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        echo "<h1>Sent Successfully! Thank you"." ".$name.", We will contact you shortly!</h1>";
    }
    else{
        echo "Something went wrong!";
    }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Where is your ajax code? Have PHP return a json object with something like: `{success: true/false, message: "Sent/Not sent"}` and add the message where you want it in the way you want it using JS in the ajax callback.

Comment: You can do it using js on success just show message to user